# The h1 tag does not change via jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im pretty novice at jquery. I have a navbar and im trying to change my  tag based on what i have selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('a').click(function (){
 the = $(this).html();
 linkvalue = $(this).attr('data-link');
 $('#whatItIs').html(the); 
 console.log(the);
 console.log(linkvalue);
 

 switch(the) {
     case "Steel Products":
      { 
       window.location.href = linkvalue;
          break;
      }
     case "Steel Doors":
         { 
          
          window.location.href = linkvalue;    
          break;
      }
     case "Digital Safes":
      {
          
          window.location.href = linkvalue;
          break;
      }
     case "Security Equipment":
      {
    
          window.location.href = linkvalue;
          break;
      } 
     case "Storage Solutions":
      {
       
          window.location.href = linkvalue;
          break;
      }
     case "Steel Furniture":
      {
          
          window.location.href = linkvalue;
          break;       
         }         
     default:
     {
         console.log("Not Found");
         //window.location.href = "404.html";
     }
 }
 });
});
```

```html
<li class="dropdown" class="active">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manufactured Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Steel Products</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Steel Doors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Digital Safes</a>
                            </li >
                            <li>
                                <a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Security Equipment</a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Storage Solutions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                <a data-link ="securityEquipment.html">Steel Furniture</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

<h1 class="page-header" id="whatItIs">
                Untitled
<!--                     <small>Subheading</small>
 -->                </h1>
```

The problem is that the h1 changes for only a second and then changes back to the original  i have set it to.
This seems pretty simple. i dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: it's because you are loading a new page on each link that you click on.

Comment: Why not use the regular href attributes on the links? You seem to be replicating normal browser behaviour.

Comment: @jedifans i have to implement more functionality on this. I just havent gotten to that part. I cant seem to get this working

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald its the new pages header i need to change upon load. It changes for a second and then goes back to being untitled.

Comment: @spetiwala then you just need to update the h1 content on each page. Changing an element using jquery is not persistent when you open a new page.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald i want to change the h1 depending on what is selected.  which is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the content of `h1` to match that of a clicked link inside your list, then you can simply store the `text()` of the link in a variable once it is clicked, then updating the `h1` with it:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var title = $(this).text();
  $('#whatItIs').text(title);
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu a { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown" class="active">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manufactured Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Steel Products</a></li>
    <li><a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Steel Doors</a></li>
    <li><a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Digital Safes</a></li>
    <li><a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Security Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Storage Solutions</a></li>
    <li><a data-link="securityEquipment.html">Steel Furniture</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<h1 class="page-header" id="whatItIs">Untitled</h1>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ajqLu9vy/

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in the text editor and google chrome. Also what is the .dropdown-menu a { cursor: pointer; } you have used?

Comment: the cursor is optional. I added it only to signal that the item is clickable, since `a` tags that do not have the `href` attribute do not get the pointer cursor. Can you check the console for errors?